# Disabling the defaults of React-Query is a good idea?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I was facing issue with react-query, so i disabled the defaults to get it working but not sure if that is the best way to do it.
I was using the Autocomplete from mui to multi select option. So i was loading data on to autocomplete when component mount using useQuery and then allow user to select the multiple values. But the problem is once user select few values and after the cache gets stale it refetches on window focus and the users selected values gets lost.

```
//this is what i disabled
refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
refetchOnReconnect: false,
refetchOnMount: false,
```

my autocomplete looks like this, projects is the array that hold values from api which i get through useQuery

```
<Autocomplete
   multiple
   limitTags={2}
   disablePortal
   id="project-select"
   noOptionsText="No project, click + to create new!"
   value={projectSelected}
   onChange={(event, newValue) => {
         setProjectSelected([
            ...projects.filter(({projectId})=> existingProjects.find((a)=> a === projectId) ),
            ...newValue.filter(({projectId}) => existingProjects.find((a)=> a === projectId) === undefined),
                ]);
              }}
/>
```

value={projectSelected} // this is the local state variable to hold what user is selecting.. but unfortunately this gets reset on background fetch.

Any guidance on this?

Comment: So you've identified the symptom, what is the cause. useQuery alone can't cause your state to be reset. Where is the state for projectSelected defined and where is it controlled?

Comment: @ChadS. 
projectSelected is handled in the same component. So basically I have one userName dropdown where I select one user & i make api call to get the projects list for that user and use this list to set the selected values in the above autocomplete... and I can also now add more project to the selected user by selecting from autocomplete that what u can see in the onChange callback above.
Projects list is list of all projects and existingProjects list is all projects of selected user. so setSelectedProject is called twice, one on onChange and other is when i call api to get user projects

Comment: `and other is when i call api to get user projects` This is the part of the code causing your issue. But you've not shown it so we can't help you yet.

Comment: So the problem is refetchOnWindowFocus triggers the api call to get the projects of the user and update the selectedProject state back which removes what use has selected before of focusing the window :(

Comment: let me share that piece of code @ChadS.

Comment: ```
useQuery(['getProjectsByUserId', user?.userId as number], 
    async () => await getProjectsByUserId(user?.userId as number), 
    { 
      enabled: !!user.userId , 
      onSuccess: (data: Project[]) => {
        let userProjects: Project[] = []
        (data).forEach(item => {
            userProjects.push(projects.find(project=> project.projectId === item.projectId) as Project);
        })
        setProjectSelected(userProjects);
      } 
    }
  )
```
This is getting called every time i select any user from dropdown and the user api is called to get the user details.

Comment: You almost definitely do not want to use any onSuccess handler for your useQuery. Instead you should be using the data that useQuery returns directly and deriving your state from that.

Comment: You mean the onSuccess is not useful in my usecase or generally we should avoid using it? What is the ideal case for onSelect could please help me understand. 
I have used onSelect in lot of places in my code usually to set the state that needs to be passed to child component or which can be modified by user through UI and also when I want to make mutation call after the query fetch result in success.
Thanks @ChadS.

Comment: That it's not useful for almost any use-case. You should be deriving your state (either by memo or by select function passed as options). Then you won't have this issue. If you edit your question to instead ask how to correctly derive the state and post the current code you have for the `useQuery` call I can write an answer to that question.

Comment: Sure @ChadS., il edit the question in sometime and tag you. Thanks for all your support.